# Contract calls don't return values sent with contract executions in DevelopmentChain mode

Tags: contract-development, parity

I'm using parity 1.5.2 dev chain.

```
./parity --chain chain.json ui
```

where chain.json is from [default configuration](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Private-development-chain)

Test contract is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.9;

contract Test {
  event Ev(string key);

  mapping(string => string) mapp;

  function setMapping(string key, string val) {
    mapp[key] = val;
    Ev(key);
  }

  function getMappingVal(string key) constant returns(string) {
    return mapp[key].val;
  }

}
```

`setMapping` tx is immediately mined every time.
But events aren't sent sometimes. And `getMappingVal` returns an empty string at the same time.

The same contract works fine for every tx, for example, with Ropsten chain (--testnet).

How to fix this behaviour in dev chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue [is not reproduced with Parity 1.5.4](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/issues/4527).